# How do I place nodes around a circle in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circles

I'd like to place 17 evenly-spaced nodes around a circle. I am very new to Tikz and am following the Petri nets example in the manual. I would like to do something similar — essentially just recreating a better version of [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Heroesjourney.svg), complete with all the steps described in the Wikipedia article.

Does anyone know how to place the nodes in this way? I'd appreciate and all advice!

Answer (score 29):

Time to call `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a in {1,2,...,17}{
\draw (\a*360/17: 4cm) node{angle \a};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, that works nicely for most of it, however I have a few issues: firstly, will I still be able to connect each "angle a" with arrows? Secondly, all of my nodes are named differently; how might I label them individually? Thanks for this first step though, I hadn't thought of \foreach!

Comment: @AYT Please don't *slowly* build-up the question. Your linked picture is not that innocent to be formulated as *put 17 nodes around a circle*.

Comment: @AYT, use a second variable. But you'll have to describe it one by one until number 17. `\foreach \a/\t in {1/one,2/two,<insert here the others>,17/seventeen}`. Then you can use `\t` on the code.

Comment: @Sigur That's more or less worked, though I'm having some issue with [the spacing](http://i.imgur.com/uzp8I22.png). Any idea how to fix it? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Since you need nodes with different widths I recommend to look for another method. You can split the nodes in blocks and insert using different radius.

Comment: @Sigur: You can do the loop even simpler: `\foreach \a [count=\c] in {<label1>,<label2>,...,label17>}{\node at (\c*360/17:4) {\a};}`

Answer (score 8):

With PSTricks' ultimate macro `\curvepnodes`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\degrees[10]
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=11]{0}{10}{2.7 t \pst@angleunit PtoC}{A}
    \psnccurve[showpoints](0,9){A}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{10}{\uput[\i](A\i){$A_{\i}$}}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes: Herbert or other PSTricks maintainers, please give me an RPN operator `angleunit` to avoid typing `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` that consumes more keystrokes.

### Animation

How to gradually make a circle with a closed curve of variable points.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\multido{\iA=2+1}{20}{%
\def\N{\iA}
\degrees[\N]
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1]{0}{\N}{2.7 t \pst@angleunit PtoC}{A}
    \psnccurve(0,\numexpr\N-1){A}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\N}{\uput[\i](A\i){$A_{\i}$}}
\end{pspicture}}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about graph?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[clockwise, radius=4cm, n=17]
    {
        label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8,label9,label10,label11,label12,label13,label14,label15,label16,label17;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Adding arcs to it is as easy as writing `label1->[bend right]label2;`.

I'm quite confident there is a shorter way to set labels, but I don't know about it right now, sorry.

[image: rendered image]

Comment: Welcome! The [`necklace routing`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662314/16595) can make the connection between the nodes lie on the circle.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I came here because I was looking for something similar but much more graph related, that's why I commented on this. Thank you!
The only issue I see on necklace routing is that the ring covers the nodes too, as shown on the image on your answer!

Comment: No, I've added the gray circle to show that the edges lie perfectly on the circle. (See the heading.) It isn't generated by the code or the library.

Comment: Just noticed, sorry

Comment: No problem, I didn't explain it very good in my answer.