# Basic undirected graphs in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

Hey TeX Stack Exchangers,

I have to draw some really basic undirected graphs in TikZ and struggling to find documentation that fits my needs. Each of my graphs has **10 edges** and an equal number of degrees per vertice. I want to draw 3 graphs as follows:

1. A graph with 20 nodes each with a degree of 1
2. A graph with 10 nodes each with a degree of 2
3. A graph with 5 nodes each with a degree of 4

I obviously don't want to hand code all of these nodes and edges. I've been playing around with loops in TikZ but it is really frustrating. The closest thing I found for graph #2 is [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145379/how-do-i-place-nodes-around-a-circle-in-tikz) but it isn't much help.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar! Turns out my problems are solved easily with tkz-berge. One of the hardest things about starting out with LaTeX is knowing what things are called in order to look them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a special package for graphs it is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetVertexMath
\grEmptyPath[prefix=v,RA=2,RS=0]{5}
\grEmptyPath[prefix=w,RA=2,RS=3]{5}
\EdgeIdentity{v}{w}{5}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\SetVertexMath
\grCycle[RA=2]{10}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\SetVertexMath
\grComplete[RA=2]{5}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

See documentation of tkz-berge.

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't know this package existed. I will definitely dive in!